# Break label into multiple lines programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey i want to break my label into lines using c#.
this is what i get from listview
[image: output]

i tried css and javascript but no success

this is my aspx

```
      <ItemTemplate>
      <span style="">
      text:
      <asp:Label ID="textLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("text")%>' />
      </span>
      </ItemTemplate>
```

and this is what i want

[image]

Comment: You could try wrapping: http://geekswithblogs.net/StealThisCode/archive/2006/03/21/WrapLabels.aspx

Comment: @tnw thanks for your help, but i dont want to limit my rows or size, i want it like facebook post's for example with no ending.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? E.g. post original string (partially if it's too long) and also the way you want it to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Labels render as SPANS, you can target those spans, by limiting thing their width and breaking words. Try adding this style to your page:

```
span[ID*="textLabel"]{
    display:block;
    max-width:200px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Note `*=` selector - it will select all labels that have `textLabel` in their ID - handy for selecting items within ItemTemplate.

Having this style you can do whatever you want with your labels: stretch, condense, add scrollbars etc. - anything that is allowed in CSS.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5jJT9/**